# Dialog box of animatedModal.js makes link not clickable (even though it has z-index:-9999)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [animatedModal.js](http://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/) to get some simple dialog boxes.
Everything is working like a charm, but I can't click the link on my logo on the top of my page, because the modal with

```
opacity:0;
z-index:-9999;
```

is in front of it. It's behind all the other stuff and opacity is 0, like it should, but somehow it's still *in front* of the logo. The logo got `z-index:100`, but still the invisible modal is in front of it.

Because I couldn't find an online version of `animatedModal.js` (like cdnjs.com or smth), I can't make a fiddle, but you can check out my webpage here:

- [The full site](http://tobiasgla.us/portfolio)
- and the [animatedModal.js](http://tobiasgla.us/scripts/animatedModal.min.js) on my site

Comment: You can try to add to this class: `animatedModal1-off`the css property `display: none`and `animatedModal1-on` the property `display: block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite simple. You are losing the track of the z-index. I don't have all the spot where you set your z-index but I found this two to be crucial:

- Your a tag (class=logo) has z-index of 100
- Your div tag (class=content) has z-index of 200

So the browser will understand that you always want you content to be above your a tag. So, keep this in mind, let's see how you set up your z-index for modal.

- Your modal has z-index of -9999, which is relative to its parent (content) => which means it actually has z-index of 200.(-9999).

This means no matter what z-index you have on the logo, it will always below your modal:

TL;DR:
The fix is set the content z-index to be lower than your a tag. Or reorganize your DOM since modal doesn't need to be next to the call link. If you choose second one, set a tag z-index might kick in.

Comment: Thanks! And yes, I chose the 2nd one, since the logo _needs_ to be behind the content. Copying all the modals out of the `.content` div made the trick :) Thanks alot!

Comment: glad I can help :D. Accept my answer for further researcher :)